# Call all dictionary values with the same key in Flask

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

I have a selectpicker multiple checklist of "tags" that you can add to a large form. When that form is submitted to the Flask Server, it sees that multiple "tags" are coming, but none of the code I write selects all of the values, just the first one.

Here is an example form submitted:

`ImmutableMultiDict([('Page', u'Generic'), ('tags', u'Health'), ('tags', u'Local Community'), ('tags', u'Regional News'), ('author', u'Author Name'), ('Title', u'Title Name')])`

When I try to iterate over the Dictionary I get:

````
for value in formData.keys():
            print formData[value]

> Generic
> Health
> Author Name
> Title Name``` 

I am missing "local Community" and "Regional News"
````

Comment: ```for key in formData.keys():
            app.logger.info(key)
            app.logger.info('===================')
        for value in formData.values():
            # app.logger.info(formData[value])
            app.logger.info(value)
            app.logger.info('===================')``` still skips all tags after the first one.

Comment: I believe if your key has multiple values then you need to access it by the `getlist()` function. `formData.getlist('tags') > [u'Health', u'Local Community', u'Regional News']`.